# Can we further simplify the closed solution to the Goat Problem?

Tags: geometry, recreational-mathematics, closed-form, complex-integration

This year, there was published a [closed-form solution](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s00283-020-09966-0) to the [Goat Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Goat_problem). The problem seeks the radius of a circle (teal) with center on the edge of a unit circle (green) such that the first circle overlaps half of the unit circle.

[image: Image from https://mathworld.wolfram.com/GoatProblem.html]

The solution given is

$$r=2\cos\left(\frac{{\Large\oint}_{\large|z-3\pi/8|=\pi/4}{\Large\frac{z}{\sin{z}-z\cos{z}-\pi/2}}dz}{{\Large\oint}_{\large|z-3\pi/8|=\pi/4}{\Large\frac{2}{\sin{z}-z\cos{z}-\pi/2}}dz}\right)= 1.15872847\dots$$

Can we simplify this further? I noticed that the divided integrals look like a center of mass formula.  I tried converting the contour integrals into real integrals, but didn't get very far. I don't have much experience with complex integration. Also, I don't have access to the paper, but maybe there is some information there that can help us.

Comment: I wouldn't call that a "closed form", because you can evaluate the integrals only numerically. It's just residues the other way round, and you could write it with only one integral, obviously.

Answer (score -3):

Yes, we can further simplify the closed solution to the Goat Problem:

I wrote an article about a simple and I think elegant solution to the Goat Problem several years ago.
Here's a link to it:

https://www.keepandshare.com/doc6/41009/cow-goat-grazing-inside-a-circular-pasture-problem-pdf-513k?da=y

Comment: [Here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) is a MathJax tutorial. Also, try inserting the imgur link to the diagram.

Comment: Sorry, I'm confused about how this can be considered a closed-form solution.

Comment: Is it closed form?  I asked Google A I Bard about it. Bard seems to know what closed form is.  I gave it the equation, and here's what it said: "Yes, the equation ∫(2r⋅cos−1(r/2))dr=π/2 is in closed form." And it followed that with a long and mathematically detailed explanation.